# Monotone Convergence Theorem with summation

Tags: real-analysis

Show if a sequence $(f_n)_n$ in $L_1$ is such that $\sum ^\infty _{n=1} \|f_n\|_1<\infty$, then $\sum ^\infty _{n=1} |f_n(s)| < \infty$.

Hint: Use the Monotone Convergence Theorem.

I am so confused with how to use integral and summation at the same time.

I have no clue how to start....

Please help me .....
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Note that $S_n(s)=\sum ^n _{k=1} |f_n(s)|$ is an increasing non-negative sequence, so the monotone convergence theorem applies to say that

$\lim\int S_n=\int \lim S_n=\int S$. But,

$\lim\int S_n=\lim\int \sum ^n _{k=1} |f_n|=\lim \sum ^n _{k=1}\int|f_n|=\lim \sum ^n _{k=1}\|f_n\|= \sum ^{\infty} _{k=1}\|f_n\|<\infty$, so

$\int S<\infty$ so $S=\sum ^\infty _{k=1} |f_n(s)| <\infty$  almost everywhere.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It is really helpful. By the way, how and why '$\int S<\infty$' implies '$S=\sum ^\infty _{k=1} |f_n (s)|<\infty$' almost everywhere?
I am having a hard time justifying this.

Comment: [This link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1487172/if-f-is-integrable-is-it-finite-almost-everywhere/1487220) might help.