# $\{r_n: n = 1,2,...\}$ enumeration of the rational numbers in $[0, 1]$. Show $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}f(|x - r_n|)$

Tags: real-analysis

$f$ is a non-negative Lebesgue integrable function on $[0, 1]$, and $\{r_n: n = 1,2,...\}$ is an enumeration of the rational numbers in $[0, 1]$. I want to show:
\begin{equation}
       \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}f(|x - r_n|)
   \end{equation}

converges for a.e. $x \in [0, 1]$.

I know that since $f$ is Lebesgue integrable, it follows that $\int_0^1 |f|dx < \infty$. However, I'm not sure how I would use this to solve the problem.

Comment: Could the sum $=\infty$ on a set of positive measure?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than solving the problem entirely I will give a hint:

You will use the idea that since f is integrable, the measure of the set of values x which take f(x) bigger than an upper bound M will go to zero in measure as the upper bound goes to infinity. In the case where the sum doesn't converge the values that f takes on will have to exceed the bounds too fast because of that one over 2 to the n in the front of the sum, this will force the measure of such places to approach 0.

Answer (score 1):

For each $n$ is
$$
\int_0^1 f(|x - r_n|)\, dx = \int_0^{r_n} f(r_n-x) \,dx + \int_{r_n}^1 f(x-r_n) \, dx \le 2 \int_0^1f(x) \, dx \, .
$$
The function
$$
 F(x) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}f(|x - r_n|)
$$
is nonnegative, measurable, and
$$
 \int_0^1 F(x) \, dx = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}\int_0^1  f(|x - r_n|) \, dx
\le 2 \int_0^1f(x) \, dx < \infty
$$
which implies that $F(x) < \infty$ a.e. on $[0, 1]$ (see for example [If f is integrable, is it finite almost everywhere?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1487172/if-f-is-integrable-is-it-finite-almost-everywhere/1487220)).